# Returning two different output of one variable

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

This is a script I've written for Google Forms to allow respondents to have a record of participating while remaining anonymous. The script records a unique ID for each respondent to a spreadsheet *and* provides that ID on a confirmation page (message) to the respondent upon hitting "submit" (= the trigger for the script to run). The problem is that it logs to the spreadsheet correctly, but it provides the previous respondent's ID to the confirmation page. Is it retaining a previous variable (randomUnique)? Is it fetching an object from the spreadsheet?

```
function setUniqueId(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1n_SPREADSHEETCODEHERE_ek');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');

  var row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var randomUnique = `CLASS_MODEL-${Math.random().toString(32).slice(2, 8)}`

  var form = FormApp.openById("18_FORMCODEHERE_78")
  var message = `Hello, this is a check for completion. Your unique ID is ${randomUnique}. 
    Please print this paper and bring it to your instructor if required for class.`

  form.setConfirmationMessage(message) //present unique id to respondent
  sheet.getRange(row, 2).setValue(randomUnique) //logs to the spreadsheet
}
```

It logs fine, it just gives the wrong code (that is, it gives the previous code) on the confirmation page. [I've redacted the IDs for the spreadsheet & form.]

Comment: When are you calling `setUniqueId`? If you're calling it when the user submits, it will show the confirmation message from the *previous* submission.

Comment: Yes, it calls when the user submits. But Google Apps Scripts only provides triggers "on open" and "on submit". Any way around this?

Comment: This is the typical function of the script. It is not possible to modify a form when it is being accessed by someone. The reason users observe the unique ID from the prior submission is due to it being the existing value for that element when the current user presses the submit button. You could maybe send an email with that information after users hit the submit button, or you can assign that uniqueID to the row after the last one.. so when someone submits the form the row with data from its submission will be at the spot of the correct Unique ID

Comment: I think you want to run this when the user opens the script, not when they submit. Then the confirmation will match what's put into the row. Or set the confirmation message when they open, and fill in the cell when they submit.

Comment: @Matias I can't figure out how. It gets into a math loop because .getRange reads the inputted ID and goes below that (if I add +1), and then effectively creates two spreadsheets because Forms is still writing in sequence. So if I add -1 to .getLasRow, then I end up needing to add more to .getRange, etc.

Comment: @Bermar - I tried that initially, but I had problems maintaining a constant variable for the ID over two functions. Running together fixes the issue, but creates this one.

Comment: I made it work. I am gonna post it now as an answer ;)

Comment: Deleted my answer as it is not 100% functional. if 2 people or more have the form Open at the same time, they all will get the same uniqueIDPass. I believe what PGSystemTester suggests is the closest to what you need.

Answer (score 2):

The only way you could do what you're trying to achieve as far as confirmation is to instruct the user to note the exact time when they submitted. Tell them to note the time down to the second and hope that no other student was very close.... (not ideal)

A better approach would be to add a single-line text item field to your form that allows users to enter an alias that only they would recognize. You then can post the alias joined with whatever other data they submitted to confirm the submission.